# TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable when dispalying text on label

Tags: python, tkinter

I would like the text of `label134534` to be whatever the value inside workout_stuff[1,1]

I have researched this problem before but none of them were applicable to my problem or very helpful

```
workout_stuff = [['Inner Chest Push', 'Dumbell Press', 'Cable Crossover', 'Bench Press'], [], [], [], ['Cable Pushdowns', 'Overhead Barbell Extensions'], [], []]
None
label134534 = Label(canvas, text = workout_stuff[1,1])
label134534.pack()
```

The `workout_stuff` array is this:

```
[['Inner Chest Push', 'Dumbell Press', 'Cable Crossover', 'Bench Press'], [], [], [], ['Cable Pushdowns', 'Overhead Barbell Extensions'], [], []]
```

It should output whatever is in `workout_stuff[1,1]`.

Comment: Have you tried workout_stuff [1][1]

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that replicates the problem.

Comment: It is Minimal. It is complete. It is verifiable. What is wrong with this. it contains everything needed!!!

Comment: It is not what is considered an MCVE. Did you read the link posted by Bryan? Can you copy your code and run it? No. Does it say what `excercises_label` ist supposed to be? No. Please make it easier to help you!

Comment: Have a look now. I made a mistake with `exercises_label`, but other then that its all MCVE

Comment: So what _does_ label134534 contain when you run your code?

Comment: It's not complete -- it's missing an import statement. It also doesn't create the root window or the canvas.  Also, if we put in reasonable guesses for all of those missing pieces, the code does not give the error you say it does. If we make a reasonable guess at fixing the error it actually throws, the next error is still not the error you say you get.

Comment: I am sorry, but the comments are not meant to make your life harder. The thing is that Stack Overflow gets a _lot_ of questions per minute, and when you post a question that does not give all the information you have and make it as _easy as possible_ to help you, your question is at risk of getting buried quickly under the amount of questions that do. It also is at risk of getting downvoted or closed. So, it would be best to show more of the code you got, post a small _self-contained_ example that shows the problem. Maybe you could also show the current (faulty) output that you get.

Answer (score 1):

Please try print out what the value of workout_stuff[1][1] is or what you are expecting.

When I print out workout_stuff[1] it gives me [] that means an empty list.
Of course an empty list can't have a workout_stuff[1][1] item!

So if you try to get the workout_stuff[1][1] item you will get an IndexError instead.

You should try to fill your list like this one:

```
workout_stuff = [['Inner Chest Push', 'Dumbell Press', 'Cable Crossover', 'Bench Press'], 
            ["hello", "noob"], [], [], ['Cable Pushdowns', 'Overhead Barbell Extensions'], [], []]
```

Now if you try workout_stuff[1][1] you will get a subscriptable object.
Let me know which item you get!